# Alfresco server throwing Connection Refused Error along with lucene parser exception in Solr4 alfresco-5.2.0 d version

Tags: lucene, alfresco-share, solr4, connectionexception

I am using alfresco-community-5.2.0 version and solr4. Getting the following error while hitting from my API. What can be the solution. Am not getting the exact solution. Can anyone give me a solution for this to try. Following is the error am getting in alfresco log and Solr log

**alfresco log**

```
ERROR [org.quartz.core.JobRunShell] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-4] Job DEFAULT.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'run' on target class [class org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor] failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 0320217066 
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:321)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:114)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 0320217066 
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:540)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:51)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:348)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:152)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:66)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.AbstractSearcherComponent.query(AbstractSearcherComponent.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor661.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.query(SearchServiceSubSystemDelegator.java:91)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor$1$1.execute(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:245)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:326)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor$1.doWork(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:234)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor.runInternal(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:229)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.DynamicCollectionProcessor.run(DynamicCollectionProcessor.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor706.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:312)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:656)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:460)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.postQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:601)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.postSolrQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:559)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:520)
    ... 28 more
```

**solr log**

```
 ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@2dc6565_Worker-26] Tracking failed
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:472)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.executeMethod(AbstractHttpClient.java:135)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.sendRemoteRequest(AbstractHttpClient.java:111)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.HttpClientFactory$HttpsClient.sendRequest(HttpClientFactory.java:408)
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getAclChangeSets(SOLRAPIClient.java:165)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.checkRepoAndIndexConsistency(AclTracker.java:354)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.trackRepository(AclTracker.java:320)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.doTrack(AclTracker.java:111)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:190)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:54)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Comment: Any solution? I am facing same issue